# Unable to do functionality with radio box in angular2

Tags: angular

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="step1.addInfoLinks" [checked] = "step1.addInfoLinks" name="addInfoLinks" value="true">     

<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="step1.addInfoLinks" [checked] = "!step1.addInfoLinks" name="addInfoLinks" value="false">     

<div class="fields" id="addInfoLinks" [hidden] = "!step1.addInfoLinks"></div>

export class Step1Component {    
    step1;     
    constructor( private _globalService: GlobalService){      
        this.step1 = {     
            addInfoLinks:false     
        }     
    }       
}
```

I have code like this. Whenever i click yes div should be visible and visaversa. Now when I click to yes able to view the div, but radio box is selected to no only. What is the problem here. Please let me know

Comment: Have you tried without `[checked] = "step1.addInfoLinks"`?

Comment: Yes. Its not working.. Whatever I click its selecting 'No' radio box and able to view the div always

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `[checked] = "..."` because the `[ngModel]="..."` part takes care of this already.

You should add `[]` around `value` otherwise the value will be the string `"true"` and `"false"` instead of the values `true` and `false` which would also not work with `"!step1.addInfoLinks">` because both strings are truthy.

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="step1.addInfoLinks" name="addInfoLinks" [value]="true">     
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="step1.addInfoLinks" name="addInfoLinks" [value]="false">
```

Comment: Tried with this, still same :(

Comment: What Angular2 version and what forms module are you using?

Comment: With beta.7 this is expected. Radio buttons were fixed not to long ago in the new forms module. You should use at least `RC.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="step2.addInfoLinks" [checked] = "step1.addInfoLinks==false" name="addInfoLinks" value="false">
```

Comment: Need to use two variable ? ie step1 and step2 ?